# can ISO-8859-1 encode MD5 bytes correctly ?

Tags: java, md5, decode, encode

1.There is some data in String:

```
String data = "some......";
```

2.And use MD5 covert it into bytes:

```
byte [] result = MD5.toMD5(data);
```

3.Now I encode it into String:

```
String encodeString = new String(result,"ISO-8895-1");
```

4.And then decode it to bytes:

```
byte [] decodeBytes = encodeString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Here my question is : **Will the `decodeBytes` be equal to `result` ?**

My confusion is whether there will be `Zero` in `result` and will it cause **truncation** in **Step3** ?

If there is any problem to let `decodeBytes` equal to `result`, and if I limit the data type of String in Step1 such as just allow **Letters and Numbers** , will the problem can be avoid?

Comment: Java strings aren't null-terminated, so there's no problem with zero bytes.  Not all character encodings can be round-tripped through, which may be a problem, but I'm not sure about this particular encoding.  (Note that you probably want to display the hash as hexadecimal instead of directly converting its bytes.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I know the hexadecimal String , but now I'm facing some library's strange usage like this.

Comment: You probably won't be able to retrieve the original hash, no.  You'll _need_ to change step 3.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I found the native function in http://osxr.org/android/source/libcore/luni/src/main/native/java_nio_charset_Charsets.cpp at line 128. It seems that ISO-8859-1 doesn't do the real encode , so I think the usage is safety , am I right?

Comment: 'Some library' such as what? 'Strange usage' such as what? Does it really expect to receive an MD5 as a `String`?

Comment: @EJP It really want I pass MD5 as `String`, the library just want its API compatible with other conditions , but I don't think it's good idea to do like this. `Strange usage` is what I post in the question. And the library is internal library in my company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why a byte value should not be decoded to a character if ISO-8859-1, which is a 8 bit character code. Although 65 code points (for control characters) are not included, the String methods handle these as if the conrols defined in ISO/IEC 6429 were part of that character set.

Round tripping byte values 0 to 255 works perfectly, also with byte[].

```
byte[] bs = new byte[256];
String encode() throws Exception {
    return new String( bs, "ISO-8859-1" );
}
byte[] decode( String s ) throws Exception{
    return s.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" );
}
 void set(){
    for( int i = 0; i < bs.length; ++i ){
        bs[i] = (byte)i;
    }
}
boolean cmp( byte[] x ){
    for( int i = 0; i < bs.length; ++i ){
        if( bs[i] != x[i] ){
            System.out.println( i + ": " + bs[i] + " != " + x[i] );
            return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
void round() throws Exception{
    String s = encode();
    if( s.length() != 256 ) throw new IllegalStateException();
        byte[] res = decode( s );
        if( ! cmp( res ) ) System.out.println( "false" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me bad English, my understanding is the byte[] can be round-tripped in ISO-8859-1, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I actually ran the round-trip. See added code. - UTF-8 would definitely not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Save me days!